# Using Rules How can I Remove a role from ANY user not just current user

Tags: users, rules

I have a use case for a project where a user of specific role has access to the site during specific dates. What I want to occur is- when the date passes the user loses his role and access to the site.

Currently, I have this rule working on Cron run, but the only option to me is to react on site:current-user. Is there a way to react on ANY user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible approach to make this work, is to *process the results of a [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) enabled view via [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)*, whereas your rule performs 2 Rules Actions:

- load the VBO list of users that you want to be processed.
- add a loop to perform a Rules Action, probably similar to the rule you already have in place, for each user contained in your Views results.

For more details, have a look at the tutorial "[How to process the results of a VBO enabled view via Rules?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/90)".

Comment: Thank you for the VBO suggestion, this worked perfectly!

Comment: @MRC : merci for the confirmation! Next question?